Low latency in RPC node (~30 seconds delay)
I am trying to develop an snipe bot but when detecting new pools from Raydium I detect them between 20-40 seconds after creation.
I have tried with QuickNode and Helius RPC nodes, but I don't see a big difference.
Helius offers dedicated RPC nodes but it costs 1.800-2.400 USD/month... too much to test them.
I think it is not possible to test them just buy paying a few days.
Has anybody tested it for snipping?, how long does it take it to detect a new pool?
Have you trying by creating your own node?, what latency have you reached?, server cost?

Getting close to real-time detection of new LP-pools on raydium can be quite trivial and don't have to cost that much.
I have achieved this using Helius's geyser rpc endpoints with their transaction subscribe method. This processes generally faster than the normal program subscribe that you would do on a "vanilla" rpc client.
The second thing that affects how fast you will be detecting new pools, is the commitment level which you subscribe to. While finalized guarantees that the pool is created and is fetchable, you can use both processed or confirmed to speed things up significantly. As you then get the trigger when the transaction hits the validator, and not after the vote is complete.
Hope this helps your endeavor and best of luck

Many thanks, I will check both options.

Helius's geyser rpc endpoints needs a business plan which starts at 499$ (https://www.helius.dev/pricing) and there is no option to test it before contracting it.

It seems latitud.sh (https://www.latitude.sh/pricing) has servers ready to mount in 3 clicks and you can pay per hour (so that you can test the service without paying a full month).

I reached a latency of less than 3 seconds by using Helius's geyser rpc.
It's impossible to improve the detection latency of the new pool of raydium if you use the event hook method with rpcs including helius, quicknode.
It takes about 20~40 seconds to detect in case of using the event hook method even though you are with the high-performance rpcs.
It would help you to use callback or webhook, or grpc to improve the detection latency.

Helius's geyser rpc cost 499$ which could be affordable, but first I would need to test them and seems that it is not possible for free or at a lower cost. Thank you.

You can test with grpc on shyft. Price is $199 every month. I tested with it. And detection latency was about 3~4s.

Here is a list of RPC providers: https://solana.com/rpc
It seems like Triton and Helius have good reputation.
In Triton's case it seems that they offer 400 ms latency with a dedicated RPC node that costs 2.000 USD/month.
Helius offers 1.800 and 2.400 USD/month services but I can't see any reference to their latency.
But I don't find a way to test these services for free (not even for a short test).

Have you tried ask the guys at http://DedicatedNodes.IO? They could possibly advise something when it comes to Solana nodes. Really good pros there. Lots of praising in discord about their custom engineering.

I will check them, thanks.

I meet the same problem when getting LiquidState on Raydium (to calculate realtime token's price). The latency is about 15 - 20 seconds. I've already tried with PRC from Quicknode, Helius and Chainstack (the cheapest paid versions), but there was no improvement.
I am not sure it is the PRC's problem or Raydium's problem. Have anybody have solution for this?
Thank you!
